# Postgresql aggregate with group by many columns

Tags: postgresql

How can I aggregate this table into a one line json object?

[image]

With request like this:

```
select 
    tb.book_id,
    json_agg(json_build_object('id', t.id, 'name', t.name, 'likes', tb.likes) order by tb.likes desc) as tags
from 
    tags_books as tb
join 
    tags as t on tb.tag_id = t.id 
where 
    tb.book_id = 2 
group by 
    tb.book_id
```

Result:

```
[{"id" : 2, "name" : "Для взрослых", "likes" : 3}, {"id" : 3, "name" : "Приключения", "likes" : 2}, {"id" : 1, "name" : "Экшн", "likes" : 1}, **{"id" : 4, "name" : "Комедия", "likes" : 1}, {"id" : 4, "name" : "Комедия", "likes" : 1}**]
```

I got almost what I want, but I need to somehow aggregate two tags in one (last line 'Комедия') and get sum of likes.

Result should be like this:

```
[{"id" : 2, "name" : "Для взрослых", "likes" : 3}, {"id" : 3, "name" : "Приключения", "likes" : 2}, {"id" : 1, "name" : "Экшн", "likes" : 1}, {"id" : 4, "name" : "Комедия", "likes" : **2**}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i was getting in wrong direction and in the end decided to split tables, so now all works fine:
[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557